# Neo4j full-text search in multiple languages on nodes with the same label

Tags: neo4j, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I try to use neo4j's new full-text search (FTS) feature. My problem, is that I would like to employ FTS on nodes with the same label (e.g. `Post`) and property (e.g. `post_text`), but the property `post_text` can be of any language. I can also hold a `language` property (or better, a relationship like `HAS_LANGUAGE`). I would like to be able to search the posts written in the language detected (using some external language detector), and to use a language analyzer that is suitable for the language detected.
While reading the relevant [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/schema/index/#schema-index-fulltext-search), I couldn't find any way to use different analyzer for nodes with the same label, but with a different `language` property. Is that possible?
**Note that in my real use case I also have a uniqueness constraint for the `post_text` property, so I can't use a different property for each language (e.g. `en_post_text`, `es_post_text` etc.)**

The only workaround I can think of is using a different label for each language (e.g. `EnglishPost`, `SpanishPost` etc.) instead of using the language property and the label `Post`. Is this solution supposed to work well?